# How to change to a different view from controller in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm retrieving a person from a service and displaying the details on the details.html template. If the person is not found, the service returns a 404 response and I handle it from within the controller by (currently) displaying an alert popup stating its not found.

Is it possible to dynamically change to a different template, like a 'notfound.html' for instance?

Comment: You can redirect to a different page using `$location.path(url)`.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way to not do a redirect. Just to keep the current path but a different view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using ng-switch directive. Save state of your request in variable (for example `$scope.items = data` if you received your data correctly or `$scope.items = false` otherwise) and then:

```
<div ng-switch on="items">
    <div ng-switch-when="false" ng-include src="'error.html'"></div>
    <div ng-switch-default ng-include src="'details.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the path to the ng-include relative to the template path?

Comment: @FanieReynders It's relative to your main file (containing <head> etc)

Comment: no its located at /people/error.html, but specifying it does not seem to work as I get a blank page.

Comment: Eventually got it working, thnks for pointing me in the right direction!